# Optimized Algorithm for Distance Matrix Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

I've been looking for an optimized algorithm for solving a distance matrix (a hollow, skew symmetric matrix), but I haven't been able to find anything but papers discussing repopulating sparse matrices and biology.  Is there a more optimal way to solve these matrices than by Gaussian elimination?

Thanks!